# List order numbers of the orders that included at least three diﬀerent parts (not quantity). Display the number of parts ordered as well?

Tags: mysql, sql, linq

I want to query a mailorder database and following is the information which I want to fetch

List order numbers of the orders that included at least three diﬀerent parts (not quantity). Display the number of parts ordered as well?
I used the below query but its only returning the first entry

```
select o.ono, od.pno 
from orders o, odetails od, parts p 
where o.ono = od.ono and od.pno = p.pno 
having count(od.pno) > 2
```

[image]

Comment: Create sample fiddle and show desired result for it.

Comment: You can use distinct in aggregate functions for example count(distinct pno)

Comment: select o.ono,od.pno from orders o,odetails od,parts p where o.ono=od.ono and od.pno=p.pno having count(od.pno)>2